# How to fail a test if a rejected promises catch?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, async-await, karma-jasmine

How to fail a test if a rejected promises catch?

I'm trying to set up an angular service test to the asynchronous sign-in function.

If it returns a rejected promise, handled by the catch, the test should fail. But the test always is a success.

**typescript**

```
it('should sign-in with email and password', async(() => {

const service: AuthService = TestBed.get(AuthService);

// the strings can't be empty the service returns a rejected promise.
service.signInWithEmailAndPassword('', '').then(user => {


  }).catch(error => {

    fail();
  });
}));
```

**karma is throwing this Error:**

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', ''fail' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error: 'fail' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
Error: 'fail' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
```

Comment: Can you try to add ``await`` for ``service.signInWithEmailAndPassword`` and see what you get ?   ``it('should sign-in with email and password', async() => {

    const service: AuthService = TestBed.get(AuthService);

    // the strings can't be empty the service returns a rejected promise.
    await service.signInWithEmailAndPassword('', '').then(user => {


    }).catch(error => {

        fail();
    });
  });``

Comment: I have tried, initially, it works but without changing any code, just running the tests again the error changes to:

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: Is your test bed working fine? Try to use fakeAsync instead of async. Also add the tick() method.